# Get install location from registry key value data

Tags: batch-file, registry

I basically want to know if its possible for me to get a path from the registry and use it in a Batch file.

Basically what I have is some code I've gather from this site

```
@echo off
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V" /v     "InstallFolder"
```

That line returns

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V
InstallFolder    REG_SZ    D:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V
```

All I want to do here is add the path of GTA to the batch file so I can then launch the executable (PlayGTAV.exe) through the batch file. The reason I'm not using the path i already know is because I want this batch file to work on some friends computers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\Interbase\Servers" ^|find " REG_SZ "') DO (
 SET "target=%%a"
)
SET "target=%target:*REG_SZ    =%"
ECHO "%target%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This should demonstrate how - I've obviously used a different key.

The `^|find...` finds the appropriate line containing the `REG_SZ` (the caret is used to tell `cmd` that the piping is of the `reg query` command, not part of the `for`) and the `for /f "delims="` selects the entire line for application to `%%a`.

From there, it's simply a matter of applying substringing to the ordinary environment variable `target` (since substringing of the metavariable `%%a` is not allowed) - replace any characters before and including the first occurrence of `REG_SZ+4spaces` with *nothing* (the string between the `=` and terminal `%`